# fancybox2 fixed width

Tags: width, fancybox

Is there a set of configs that will allow me to open a FancyBox2 popup (inline type) with a fixed, set width?  It's ok if the height flexes, but I want the width set to a particular size.

I've tried something like this:

```
$.fancybox( {content:msg, type:"inline", title:title, autoSize:false, minWidth:"250px", width:"450px", height:h, maxWidth:"450px"} );
```

But if my content happens to be wider than 450px, it just expands the view rather than using more height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set

```
width: 450
```

for a 450px wide box.

Actually all integer numbers should be written without quotes for their value in pixels so the correct syntax should be:

```
minWidth: 250,
maxWidth: 450,
width: 450
```

etc.

Additionally you should set the option `fitToView` to `false` too for a fixed size, otherwise fancybox will try to re-size the box to fit within the viewport

Comment: Well, this is a lot closer.  Now I'm using this:

``$.fancybox( {content:msg, type:"inline", fitToView:false, title:title, autoSize:false, minWidth:"450", width:"450", height:"250", maxWidth:"450"} );``

What I'm seeing now is a fancybox the right width but extremely tall--off the page.  Any ideas what that's happening?

Comment: Ok, got it!  Don't use quotes on the numbers and all is joyful.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Now fitToView is changed to autoScale

Comment: @MudaserAli : not true, `autoScale` is **NOT** a valid option in fancybox v2.x